Odoo 17 Override Blog URL
I want to serve blog posts without the BLOG_NAME-ID part of the URL.
For example right now my blog posts have the following URL:
example.com/blog/NAME-1/post-slug
I want to remove the NAME-1 part of the URL. It's totally unnecessary for me as I don't need multiple blogs.
I followed the solution on this article https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/override-url-of-websiteblog-blog-post-163831 but   now I get 404 when I click on the single post, I believe the challenge I am having is actually understanding the solution . Would appreciate your help
